# How to update quantity referencing another table php/mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update

I'm a bit of a noob and I'm sure this is fairly simple but I've tried different things and I can't get my head around it.

I have a product table that contains a category id and I want to set the quantity to 0 which is stored in another table.

This is the last thing I tried:

```
function wipeprod(){
UPDATE stock_available
    INNER JOIN
        product stock_available
        ON
        (
            product.id_category_default != 3
            OR
            product.id_category_default != 10
            OR
            product.id_category_default != 943
        )
    SET
        stock_available.quantity = 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello Drizzt, welcome to Stack Overflow. It is hard to asses what you want from just the explanation and query. Please provide sample data and expected results as tabular text to clarify your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you want to set column `quantity` in table `stock_available` to 0 for products that are not in categories 3, 10, and 943.

If so, you can use the `update ... join` syntax as follows:

```
update stock_available s
inner join product p on p.product_id = s.product_id
set s.quantity = 0
where p.id_category_default not in (3, 10, 943)
```

The main problems with your original query are:

- the `join` is missing a predicate on `product_id`
- you wanted `AND` condition rather than `OR`; `NOT IN` comes handy to shorten this.

Comment: Yes, thank you, that's exactly what I was trying to explain.
I will try that

Answer (score 0):

You can use such an update statement by use of `INNER JOIN` :

```
UPDATE stock_available s
  JOIN
       (
          SELECT id
            FROM product
           WHERE id_category_default NOT IN (3,10,943)
        ) AS p ON p.id = s.product_id
    SET
        s.quantity = 0;
```

where no need a proper query after the keyword `JOIN`